# Property name never defined on module...ViewController.player

Tags: javascript, angular

```
class ViewController {
    /**
    * @export {!client.Player}
    */
    this.player;

    coolFunc: function() {
        // console.log(this.player["name"]) --- works
        console.log(this.player.name);
    }
}
```

The following code doesn't compile, and there's an error: property name never defined on module...ViewController.player

Is there any way to fix it (so I'll be able properties using obj.property)?

I read some similar questions but they're connected with parsing json and it isn't the case here.

Comment: Can't tell with the code you shared.

Comment: post the code where you are setting this.player

Comment: @KumarGarapati it's initialized through isolated scope. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a *Player* class with the desired properties?

```
class Player {
   constructor() {
      this.name = 'John Smith';
      this.num = 15;
      this.injured = false;
   }

   name: string;
   num: number;
   injured: boolean
}

export class MyCustomComponent{
   player: Player = new Player();

   coolFunc() {
      console.log(this.player.name);
   }
}
```

**Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-68upyn